# Using variables in redshift insert command - Python lambda function

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to insert records to a redshift table using a lambda function. I am using

```
boto3.client('redshift-data')
```

for the same. Now I have the query as below.

```
query1 = "insert into dbname.tablename values('aaaa','bbbb','cccc')"

response = rsclient.execute_statement(
        ClusterIdentifier='xxxxx',
        Database='yyyy',
        DbUser='zzzz',
        Sql= query1,
        StatementName='examplestatement'
        )
```

This works fine. But I want to pass variables here instead of values. For instance,

```
var1 = 'aaaa'
var2 = 'bbbb'
var3 = 'cccc'
```

Then try the query as below but it it doesn't work, I think it something silly to do with quotes.

```
query1 = "insert into dbname.tablename values(var1,var2,var3)"
```

How can I achieve this. I write lambda function using python3. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
query1 = f"insert into dbname.tablename values('{var1}','{var2}','{var3}')"
```